# Storing file on Azure from web application and access from azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I have a requirement:

1. My ASP.NET application which is in an on-premise server will generate some reports in PDF
2. ASP.NET application should store PDF somewhere in Azure e.g.: `FolderX`
3. Azure Function should pickup files from above Azure `FolderX` and generate a summary report in PDF
4. Azure Function store generated PDFs in another azure directory e.g.: `FolderY`
5. As soon as the summary PDF is available in `FolderY`, another Azure Function application will send `FolderY` PDF file to the Administrator group.

In the above requirement, all looks ok but I am not sure how to create folder or Azure and manage files.
Do I need to create File Share in storage, or blob storage, or VM machine, and how can access from a web app and azure function app?

Please suggest.

Comment: Please, describe to us what have you done so far to solve the problem. I encourage you to read the ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide to make your question clearer and easier to answer.

Comment: I would suggest using blob storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blob storage to acheive what you want.

For example, if you are using .Net:

```
// Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

//Create a unique name for the container
string containerName = "yourcontainername";

// Create the container and return a container client object
BlobContainerClient containerClient = await blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync(containerName);
string localFilePath = "...";

// Get a reference to a blob
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

// Open the file and upload its data
using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);
await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
uploadFileStream.Close();
```

This is the offcial document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#upload-blobs-to-a-container

The basic idea is to upload files to blob storage. Let me know whether you can acheive what you want with above code.:)